# In java, what does Enumeration<?> mean?

Tags: java

What's does `Enumeration<?>` mean?

Is there any way to represent the general generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<?>` syntax is java's way to specifying that the generic type is "unbounded" - ie it can be "anything".

`Enumeration<?>` is an Enumeration with an "unbounded type" - you can assign an Enumeration of any type to such a variable, for example:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
Enumeration<String> es = v.elements();
Enumeration<?> e = es; // This assignment compiles OK
```

However, being unbounded, the nextElement() method of an `Enumeration<?>` with return type `Object` (even if it's actually an `Enumeration<String>`), so you'll have to cast if you want typed elements:

```
String s = (String)e.nextElement(); // Unsafe cast - compiler warning
```

For background, [Enumeration][1] is a typed interface with two methods [hasMoreElements()][2] and 
[nextElement()][3]. It was an early (poor) attempt that was superseded by [Iterable][4] and [Iterator][5]. A few old class use it, like [Vector][6] and [StringTokenizer][7].

Answer (score 2):

The question mark indicates that it stands for all types. Here's an [example](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html):

> In addition to concrete instantiation there so-called wildcard
>   instantiations .  They do not have concrete types as type arguments,
>   but so-called wildcards . A wildcard is a syntactic construct with a "
>   ? " that denotes not just one type, but a family of types.  In its
>   simplest form a wildcard is just a question mark and stands for "all
>   types".
>
> Example (of a wildcard parameterized type):
>
> ```
> public void printPair( Pair<?,?> pair) {   
> System.out.println("("+pair.getFirst()+","+pair.getSecond()+")");
> }
>
> Pair<?,?> limit = new Pair<String,Long> ("maximum",1024L); 
> printPair(limit);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

While it's tempting to think of the `?` as representing "any" or "all" types, it actually specifies a single, unknown type. If it really were "any", you'd expect this to work:

```
List<?> l = ...
l.add("foo");
l.add(new Date())
```

But it doesn't. That's because the type isn't known in this code, so the compiler can't tell whether you should be allowed to add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

? is the wildcard character. You can represent it as ? extends object or something of the sort which has the same effect. From my understanding wildcards are not exactly an art so far in java they need to be somewhat bounded *but dont quote me on that